# Why can't I access properties of an UI control from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I read it's not possible to access UI elements from another thread (not only GUI, but all 2 different threads) and saw a code how to workaround it, but didn't find an explanation why can't I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx) gives for not allowing this:

> Access to Windows Forms controls is not inherently thread safe. If you have two or more threads manipulating the state of a control, **it is possible to force the control into an inconsistent state**. Other thread-related bugs are possible as well, including race conditions and deadlocks. It is important to ensure that access to your controls is done in a thread-safe way.

So technically I could be possible (and maybe they left it out by-design), but the problem is the underlying code from Microsoft isn't thread safe. This has probably to do with the inner workings of Windows and it's lack of thread safety in their Win32 UI model.

Comment: Or. it is a design decision because writing thread safe UI controls is trivial - if the control is trivial - or can be a NIGHTMARE if it is not. In many cases it makes sense - i.e. a lot of things easier - when one forces subsystems into a single threaded behavior. Which is what MS did here.

Comment: @TomTom: Good point. Didn't think of that, but that would make sense performance wise too.

Comment: And it makes debugging easier. Java was not using that (years ago when I did do Java) and they took years to find a rare race condition hanging their UI libraries. I use a similar approach in trading - strategies are single threaded. Makes writing them a LOT easier and they are not slower. Actually faster as you do not need to spread locking code everywhere.

Comment: And pretty much every GUI framework made that same decision - having a thread safe GUI code/event loop/etc. is hard, a lot of work, and would take a performance hit. Instead most GUI frameworks provide a way to inject a message or code from another thread into the GUI thread.

Comment: Yes and no - as nos said, this is a standard pattern. The trade off is normally minimal and the gain in ease of programming is simply speaking astonishing ;)

Answer (score -2):

You cant make changes to the GUI from any other thread but the GUI thread(main thread). That being said you can read the data from controls (textboxes etc) from whatever thread without problems if you want to make changes to controls from another thread you need to use something like this:

```
textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
{
    textBox1.Text = "text changed from another thread";
}));
```

The downside of this is that now the thread from which you are calling this is getting blocked until this change to the textbox is done. This isnt a problem if you are updating your controls from your thread not often but if you want to do it often you need to create a 3rd thread that handles the updates depending on what the worker thread is doing. Something like this

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
Thread workThread = new Thread(dowork =>
{
    //random work
    for(int a = 0; a< 1000000;a++)
    {
        list.Add(a+" iteration");
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
});
workThread .Start();
bool updateThreadWorking = true;
Thread updateThread = new Thread(dowork =>
{
    while(updateThreadWorking)
    {
        while(list.Count > 0)
        {
            listBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                listBox.Items.Add(list[0]);
            }));
            list.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
});
updateThread .Start();
```

Now the workthread is working at full speed without getting blocked by the UI and the UI is still getting updated on the current status

Comment: Did you bother reading? Like the question? He asks WHY, not WHAT. You basically provide zero information - you repeat, with a great example, the issue, but do not explain anything.

Comment: You cannot read data from controls from another thread without problems.